# Why can a string object be reassigned again and again?

Tags: c#

Isn't `string` immutable? Why can `line` in the following example be reassigned again and again with `file.ReadLine()`? Thanks.

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = 
   new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine (line);
   counter++;
}

file.Close();

// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 15):

> Isn't string immutable?

Yes, strings are immutable.

> Why can line in the following example be reassigned again and again

`line` is not a string. `line` is a *variable* which refers to a string. Variables are called variables *because they vary*.

That might imply that this fact is a property of references. It is not.

The number 1 is immutable, right?  No matter what you do to 1, it is 1.  If you add 10 to 1 and get 11, you have not *changed* 10 or 1. 10 and 1 remain 10 and 1. The result is 11, a brand new number.

So if numbers are immutable, then why can I say:

```
int x = 1;
x = x + 10;
```

?  Because `x` is not a *number*.  `x` is a *variable which holds a number*, and **variables can vary**.

Let's think of another example. Think of something that is immutable in real life. Say, the value of a coin.  If you have a dime, there is nothing you can do to make it worth more or less than 10 cents and still have it be a dime.  Dimes are immutable.  Suppose you have a drawer that you keep exactly one coin in, and today it contains a dime.  Tomorrow you take the dime out of the drawer and put in a quarter. How did you do that, if a dime is immutable?  *Variables are like drawers*. You can change their contents, even if the objects in the drawer are immutable.

Finally, the title of your question clearly shows the fundamental cause of your confusion:

> Why can a string object be reassigned again and again?

**Objects** are not things that can be **assigned** in the first place.  **Variables can be assigned, and variables are not objects**.  Variables are **storage locations** that can contain **values**.

If you have been taught by some book that variables are a kind of object -- and *many* beginner books make this mistake -- then *throw away that book and get a decent book that is not full of lies*.  The string returned by `ReadLine` is an *object*.  A reference to that object is *assigned to the variable*.  The *value* of that variable is then *a reference to an immutable object*.

There are two things in C# that look like variables but have slightly different semantics.

First, `const` locals or fields are not *variables*, because *constants cannot vary*. If they could vary then they would be *variables*, not *constants*.  If you say

```
const string s = "Hello";
```

then not only is `Hello` immutable, but `s` is too.  You should only use `const` for things that are *logically immutable for all time*. The price of gold, the name of your bank, your last name, these things can all change.  The atomic weight of gold, the value of pi, these things cannot ever change, and so they can be `const`.  C# only allows certain types to be `const`, and only allows certain expressions to initialize a `const`.

A `readonly` field is halfway between a `const` and a variable. A readonly field is a *variable* in the constructor or field initializer, and is illegal to write to from any other location.  C# treats readonly fields as *values*, not *variables*, in all code outside of a constructor or field initializer.

Comment: *get a decent book that is not full of lies* brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

Immutable variables can be *reassigned* but not *mutated*.

In this example:

```
string s1 = "hello";
string s2 = s1; 
string s1 = "goodbye";
```

The symbol `s1` is *reassigned* to a new string object *"goodbye"*, while `s2` refers to the same original string ("hello"), because the string was never *mutated*.

Answer (score 2):

your variable 'line' should be thought of as a pointer to the string, not as the string.

The string itself cannot be changed. For example you cannot do

```
line[4] = 'a'
```

expecting to be able to change the fifth char. Contrast with c where you can do

```
mystr[4] = 'a'
```

(in most cases anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Immutable doesn't mean a reference to the object can't be reassigned, it means the object itself can't be mutated (changed).

You can reassign the for forever, but can't change any of the strings themselves.

If you made the reference a constant, then it couldn't be reassigned.